# c++ dynamic dll loading and functions defined in the loader

Tags: c++, dll

I have `Program A` (which is opensource, but I can not modify its source), and `DLL B`, which is loaded by `Program A` dynamicly.

Is there a way, to use the functions defined in `Program A` by `DLL B`?

(Might help; `Program A` has a lot of .h header files, and all the functions I need are defined `extern` in these ...)

Answer (score 0):

The extern defines that the linker that generates the A.exe can use the symbol. When you want to get the address of the symbol (function, variable,...) the symbol must be exported. This is usually not done for a program.

If your program A.exe does not provide you a pointer or means to get a pointer to a function, you are not able to use functions of the program A.exe in your DLL B.

Dirty hacks are possible though...

Comment: What kind of dirty hacks do you mean?

Comment: Something like getting the address of the function from the map file, assigning this hardcoded to a function pointer in the DLL B and pray that always the same version of program A is calling. As said, that's dirty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of such functions, it may be worth exporting them to the other library. I, for example, am working on application of 100 000 lines of code wth only 200 in executable file.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would mean modifying the source code of `Program A`, which I'm not allowed to :-(

Answer (score 0):

**If** your A program declares functions with __declspec(dllexport) or if you are able to compile your A program with your *.def file that lists DLL exports that you need in your DLL B **then** you may get that exported functions' addresses by [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API function (passing module handle of executable that you may get by name or otherwise - see [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetModuleHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Sounds nice! What about it under Linux systems? How are the functions reachable from there?